# Confusing cuda versions

Tags: cuda

I just installed the latest CUDA 9.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 according to the official instruction. But when I run the command `nvcc -V`, it still shows my cuda version is 7.5 like below.

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Also, `which nvcc` gave me `/usr/bin/nvcc` which is not under `/usr/local` folder. Is this normal? Is this a compatibility issue? I have a GTX 1080 Ti and a GTX 980. I added commands below to `.bashrc` file, but it still didn't work.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Comment: You should get rid of the CUDA stuff in usr bin. Your PATH is picking it up.

Comment: How can I get rid of it from usr bin? Thanks!

Comment: you could reinstall the OS.  Or you could familiarize yourself with the linux `rm` command.

Comment: I am familiar with `rm` command and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to remove all traces of CUDA binaries from the `/usr/bin` directory, and in the future always install the CUDA toolkit in the "default" locations at `/usr/local/cuda-XX`

To remove CUDA items from `/usr/bin`, just use the linux `rm` command as a root user.  Not sure what to remove?  Take a look in an "ordinary" CUDA install bin directory, such as `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin`

By having your CUDA install at the default locations e.g. `/usr/local/cuda-8.0` and `/usr/local/cuda-9.0` (for example), you can have "side-by-side" installs, and [switch between them by modifying](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions) the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables accordingly.

Comment: I see you giving advice about reinstalling everywhere :) and I finally could not resist and give it a try. Things seem to be working smooth-er compared to when I had nvcc installed in `/usr/bin/`...