# Cuda version for building xgboost

Tags: cmake, cuda

Trying to get `xgboost` compiled for GPU. Seems my Cuda install is broken.

```
~$ cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "7.5", but required is at
  least "8.0" (found /usr)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:386 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:949 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:113 (find_package)
```

I originally had CUDA 7.5 installed, but afterwards installed CUDA 9.1. I tried to uninstall 7.5, but probably missed something. I ran the following commands to check my Cuda version.

```
~$ which nvcc
/usr/bin/nvcc

~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17

~$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
CUDA Version 9.1.85

~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.30  Wed Jan 31 22:08:49 PST 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 

~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Feb 21 00:35:35 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.30                 Driver Version: 390.30                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 25%   46C    P2    56W / 250W |    487MiB / 11175MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001027/confusing-cuda-versions) suggests clearing cuda files in `/usr/bin`, and I have cleared the following files.

```
~$ ls /usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin
bin2c        cuda-gdbserver               nsight                       nvprof
computeprof  cuda-install-samples-9.1.sh  nsight_ee_plugins_manage.sh  nvprune
crt          cuda-memcheck                nvcc                         nvvp
cudafe       cuobjdump                    nvcc.profile                 ptxas
cudafe++     fatbinary                    nvdisasm                     uninstall_cuda_9.1.pl
cuda-gdb     gpu-library-advisor          nvlink

~$ cd /usr/bin
~$ ls /usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin | sudo xargs rm
rm: cannot remove 'computeprof': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'crt': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'gpu-library-advisor': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'nsight': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'nsight_ee_plugins_manage.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'nvcc.profile': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'uninstall_cuda_9.1.pl': No such file or directory
```

Following the question, I added new paths in `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64\
                     ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

After these changes, the system correctly references Cuda 9.1. The other diagnostic calls remain unchanged.

```
~$ which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/nvcc

~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

However, running `cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON` still fails, returning the same error. I tried restarting my computer, but it didn't help.

How can I get this to work??

Answer (score 1):

Got it working...

Removed the xgboost directory, re-cloned it from github, and then ran make. Some residual files from the make config clogging stuff?